# Conditional formatting in excel using a custom rule

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I have a relatively not so short excel rule that I use to fill in the value of a cell based on other cells in certain conditions. It compares the values of two cells (which will be parsed as dates) and writes the minimum in another cell if they are not 0s or 9999s:

```
=IFS(OR(F3=0,G3=0);0,AND(F3=9999,NOT(G3=9999));G3,AND(NOT(F3=9999);G3=9999);F3,AND(F3=9999,G3=9999);9999,TRUE,TEXT(MIN(DATE(IF(VALUE(RIGHT(F3,2))<30,2000+RIGHT(F3,2);RIGHT(F3,2));LEFT(F3,LEN(F3)-2);1);DATE(IF(VALUE(RIGHT(G3,2))<30,2000+RIGHT(G3,2);RIGHT(G3,2));LEFT(G3,LEN(G3)-2);1));"MYY"))
```

Instead of using this rule to fill in the value automatically, I would like to use it to highlight the cells wherever I make a mistake entering the values myself.

This is a visualized example of what I want to achieve:

[image]

How would I do this?

Comment: Add a conditional formatting rule based on a formula and you have the formula.

Comment: Apparently it's too long for conditional formatting, because I cannot paste the whole rule at once and when I do bit by bit, it eventually reaches a limit where I cannot enter anything anymore...